# Having an issue with character displacemet

Tags: c++

I'm reading a file with a line of text.  I'm reading the file and changing the characters based on a displacement given by the user.  While it works for some characters, it doesn't for others beyond a certain point.

My file contains this text:  "This is crazy".
When I run my code with a displacement of 20, this is what I get:
    ▒bc▒ c▒ w▒u▒▒

```
string Security::EncWordUsingRot(int rotNum, string word)
{
  rotNum = rotNum%26;
  string encWord = word;

  for (int i = 0; i < word.size(); i++)
    {
      char c = word[i];
      c = tolower(c);

      if ((c < 'a') || (c > 'z'))
        encWord[i] = c;
      else
        {
          c = (c + rotNum);
          if (c > 'z')
            c = (c - 26);
        }
       encWord[i] = c;
    }
  return encWord;
 }
```

****EDIT*****
I changed the commented sections to correct my error. I changed `unsigned char c = word[i]` back to `char c = word[i]`.  I also added another two lines of code that took care of the value of c being lower than 'a'.  I did this because I noticed an issue when I wanted to essentially return the encrypted statement to its original form.

```
string Security::EncWordUsingRot(int rotNum, string word)
{
  rotNum = rotNum%26;
  string encWord = word;

  for (int i = 0; i < word.size(); i++)
    {
      char c = word[i];  //removed unsigned
      c = tolower(c);

      if ((c < 'a') || (c > 'z'))
        encWord[i] = c;
      else
        {
          c = (c + rotNum);
          if (c > 'z')
            c = (c - 26);
          if (c < 'a')  //but I added this if statement if the value of c is less than 'a'
            c = (c + 26);
        }
      encWord[i] = c;
    }
  return encWord;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Change:

```
  char c = word[i];
```

To:

```
  unsigned char c = word[i];
```

Comment: +1: char represents a number from 0 to 127. If you rotate `z` (ASCII code 122) by more then 5, you get out of bounds.

Comment: @David - that was very helpful!  I was noticing at what number the values were screwed up on.  I just didn't relate it to the ASCII code.

Comment: @cpp - I appreciate your explanation as well.

Answer (score 0):

In C and C++ you should always pay attention to numeric overflow because the language assumption is that a programmer will never make such a mistake.

A `char` is a kind of integer and is quite often 8 bits and signed, giving it an acceptable range of -128...127. This means that when you store a value in a `char` variable you should never exceed those bounds.

`char` is also a "storage type" meaning that computations are never done using `char`s and for example

```
char a = 'z';    // numeric value is 122 in ASCII
int x = a + 20;  // 122 + 20 = 142
```

`x` will actually get the value 142 because the computation did not "overflow" (all `char` values are first converted to integers in an expression)

However storing a value bigger that the allowable range in a variable is undefined behaviour and code like

```
char a = 'z';     // numeric value is 122 in ASCII
char x = a + 20;  // 122 + 20 = 142 (too big, won't fit)
```

is not acceptable: the computation is fine but the result doesn't fit into `x`.

Storing a value outside the valid range for signed chars in a signed char variable is exactly what your code did and that's the reason for the strange observed behaviour.
A simple solution is to use an integer to store the intermediate results instead of a char.

A few more notes:

- A few functions about chars are indeed handling integers because they must be able to handle the special value `EOF` in addition to all valid chars. For example `fgetc` returns an `int` and `isspace` accepts an `int` (they return/accept either the code of the char converted to unsigned or `EOF`).
- `char` could be signed or not depending on the compiler/options; if unsigned and 8-bit wide the allowable range is 0...255
- Most often when storing a value outside bounds into a variable you simply get a "wrapping" behavior, but this is not guaranteed and doesn't always happen. For example a compiler is allowed to optimize `(char(x + 20) < char(y + 20))` to `(x < y)` because the assumption is that the programmer will never ever overflow with signed numeric values.